# How to make jest ignore type which is not js keyword and used in @react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I am setting up jest for React Native 0.68 with jest 29.0. Here is the my jest config in package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "cacheDirectory": "./cache",
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./app/utils/vendor"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 80
      }},
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)",
      "node_modules/(?!@react-native/polyfills/)",
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@react-navigation|@react-native-community|@react-navigation-redux-helpers)",
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-runtime))"
    ]
  }
```

There is only one simple test case for the project. Here is the test case:

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

However `yarn jest` throws error below:

```
 /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This is a common error but the solutions posted didn't work in my case. I think the problem is `type` which is not a javascript keyword but a `Flow` definition. The `type` is used in `@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js` and `@react-native` is being ignored in jest config. However somehow ignore of @react-native does not work here.

Comment: this is definitely a real error, because `type` is nothing in javascript, which `error-guard.js` pretends to me. It _is_ something in typescript, which would be `error-guard.ts`, so this is very much a bug in react-native, has an issue open on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33426 and looks to have been ignored for about half a year now, so you probably want to comment on that issue to let folks know it's still a problem, and then tell jest to ignore that specific file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There is still no solution posted with the GitHub issue. It seems ignored to my surprise.

Comment: Jest is effectively maintained by a single person right now. Despite the repo being on the facebook account, don't let that fool you.